Formatting a decimal with a changing "places" variable
I'm trying to write a function that will change the amount of decimal places depending on the "places" parameter passed into the function.
I ended up using if/else statements but this is very limiting.
Is there a way to directly implement the "places" variable into the format method?
I would also like it not to round if possible. And passing in "0" and "3" would return 0.000.
def decimal(num, places):
    if places == 1:
        print(f'{num:.1f}')
    elif places == 2:
        print(f'{num:.2f}')
    elif places == 3:
        print(f'{num:.3f}')


Does this answer your question? Format string dynamically

def decimal(num, places):

    print(f"{num:.{places}f}")

In my understanding, the above response addresses and resolves your issue.

This still rounds but I think this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

unrounded: f"{num:.{places + 1}f}"[:-1]
